# Cylindrical radio component identification

Tags: identification, radio, repair, restoration

As a complete novice, probably out of my depth, I'm struggling to identify this component. It appears to be a fuse, there is no continuity across it when tested. Dimensions are; 7mm long, 2.5 wide (ceramic cylinder), 2.8 wide (metal caps).

The component is part of a front panel display and speaker board for an Icom IC-Z1 ([Link to service manual](http://www.radiomanual.info/schemi/ICOM_VU/IC-Z1A_E_serv.pdf)). An old handheld radio from the 1990s.  I can't get it to power up and suspect this component may be the problem.

I've included photos of the component marked 2.0 CmU, board diagram with component outlined in yellow and parts list from the tech manual.  Unfortunately, the  tech manual I have is a low res scan and the board diagram label is not easy to read.

Thanks for reading.

[image: White Fuse?]

[image: Board Layout]

[image: Parts List]

Comment: What happens if you sniff it with your scope? Is there a 2MHz sine wave or do you get nothing?

Comment: Good suggestion thanks. I'll see if I can get my hands on a scope.

Answer (score 2):

That's X1, a 2 MHz ceramic resonator.

Comment: Thank you so much for the speed and accuracy of info! I'm determined to get this radio working. It's going to be a long experience for me. I guess my next step will be to trace power across the boards in order to discover any dead components. Unfortunately I have no history for the radio, beyond evidence of NiCad leakage on the keyboard PCB. I've cleaned that up with white vinegar and isopropyl alcohol.  Thanks for helping me start the journey!

Answer (score 1):

According to the manual, X1 (the only feasible part you listed in the question) is a ceramic resonator used to filter the 2nd intermediate frequency: -

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for the additional information.